Getting "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found" while creating New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy
I want to dynamically create teams meeting via a single page application in PHP using the Create onlineMeeting REST API. Referencing link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Microsoft says

To use application permission for this API, tenant administrators must create an application access policy and grant it to a user to authorize the app configured in the policy to create online meetings on behalf of that user (with user ID specified in the request path)"

Approach - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy
I installed the Microsoft Teams module and was able to sign in via Connect_MicrosoftTeam. However, no matter which cmdlet I try including New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy, I am getting

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy
cmdlet New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Identity: New-Policy
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:1 char:1

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,Microsoft.Teams.ConfigApi.Cmdlets.NewCsApplicationAccessPolicy


I have only one user, that is me as a Global Administrator. I am not sure which permission I am missing.
I was hoping to create a New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy via Windows Powershell.
I am a Global Administrator so I am not sure what extra permission I can give. Even if I try to list the ApplicationAccessPolicy, I am getting the same error.
I am not able to run any type of cmdlet

The error

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

usually occurs if the command could not locate the necessary resources on the server.
I got the results successfully like below:
Copy the Application ID

And by passing the App ID I am able to create the policy like below:
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Rukpolicy -AppIds "AppID" -Description "RukPolicy"


I am able to list the application access policies:
 Get-CsApplicationAccessPolicy



Make sure to install the latest version of the MicrosoftTeams module.
Try to reinstall the module and check the Get-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams version details.
Connect to Microsoft Teams with a Global Administrator account.

If the issue still persists, check below:

Make sure that the tenant has active Microsoft 365 subscription and is not expired.
Check if any Firewall, VPN, or proxy is blocking the request.

References:
Azure - Microsoft Teams access policy - New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy returns 404 - Stack Overflow by  Ansuman Bal
PowerShell's New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy not working - Microsoft Community
